# Git-Server with Flask

Tags: python, git, flask

I'm trying to make a git server using **python (flask)**. I have private SSH access to the device for myself, but I want to make **HTTP** access for my friends without giving them access to the entire folder. It is **not an option** to restrict SSH access or create different users. Is it possible to return a git repository with flask so that it can be cloned via `git clone google.com/my/url/myProject.git`.
I use bare-repositories (myProject.git) like a normal git-server.

For Example:

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return gitRepository("./repos/myProject.git")
```

Thanks for every answer

Comment: Why not using something like [Gitea](https://gitea.io/) you can run it on your server and host your repos.

Comment: Because I try to do the GUI myself and I only need a variant to carry out a clone and pull and manage this with users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's created a simple [implementation](https://github.com/meyer1994/gitserver) of a Git server in Flask.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35531357)